# Let $A$ be a $2 \times 2$ real matrix such that $A^2 - A + (1/2)I = 0$. Prove that $A^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Question:** Let $A$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix with real entries such that $A^2 - A + (1/2)I = 0$, where $I$ is the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix and $0$ is the $2 \times 2$ zero matrix. Prove that $A^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

**My attempt:** Here is my idea so far. Consider $A$ as a $2 \times 2$ matrix over the field of complex numbers. Now, the polynomial

$$g(t) = t^2 - t + \frac{1}{2} $$

factors as

$$g(t) = \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{i}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)$$

over $C$. This means that the minimal polynomial of $A$ over $C$ is:

$$m(t) = \left(t-(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{i}{2})\right), m(t) = \left(t-(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{i}{2})\right), \ \ \ \text{ or } \ \ \ m(t) = \left(t-(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{i}{2})\right)\left(t-(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{i}{2})\right),$$

and thus we have $A = Q D Q^{-1}$, where

$$D =\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\frac{1}{2}(1 - i)}&0\\
0&{\frac{1}{2}(1 - i)}
\end{array}} \right],$$

$$D = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\frac{1}{2}(1 + i)}&0\\
0&{\frac{1}{2}(1 + i)}
\end{array}} \right],\ \ \ \text{ or } $$

$$D = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\frac{1}{2}(1 - i)}&0\\
0&{\frac{1}{2}(1 + i)}
\end{array}} \right].$$

Now, $A^n = QD^nQ^{-1}$.

Here is where I get stuck. $D^n$ doesn't seem to be converging to $0$ as $n$ approaches infinity. In addition, I am concerned that my strategy is bad, since we are talking about a real matrix and I'm using a minimal polynomial over $C$. Is it still true that $A$ must have one of the three forms above, even if $A$ is supposed to be real?

Thanks for any help/suggestions you may be able to provide.

Comment: Uh, why do your factorizations of the polynomials not have a $t$ anymore in them?

Comment: Oops, left it out - it's fixed, now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The eigenvalues of $A$ (or $D$) satisfy $|\lambda | = { 1\over \sqrt{2}} <1$. Hence
$|\lambda|^n \to 0$.

Comment: This makes sense, but I'm concerned I'm missing something, still: so, $A^n \to 0$ is equivalent to $|D|^n \to 0$ (where the absolute value is entry-wise)? I could see that this would be true if maybe $|A|^n = |Q||D|^n|Q^{-1}|$ but I don't think that is true, so I'm hoping you can clarify that piece, there!

Comment: There are various ways of answering this. With a suitable norm you have $\|A\| \le \|Q\| \|D^n\| \|Q^{-1}\|$. Alternatively, note that by continuity, if $D^n \to 0$, then $A^n \to 0$. Does this address your concern?

Comment: Ah, I see - both of those explanations work beautifully, thank you!

Comment: Uh oh, wait, now I am concerned that I've screwed up my part of the proof - I guess that if the minimal polynomial is one of the first two options, $A$ might now be diagonalizable even over $C$. Hmmmm.

Comment: The eigenvalues are complex and since the matrix is real, they must occur in conjugate pairs. Hence it is diagonalisable.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

While the answer provided by @cooper.hat is probably the one you want (as it finishes your otherwise correct proof), I would like to offer a different approach.

If $A^2=A-(1/2)I$, then multiplying by $A$ repeatedly and using induction, we see that $A^n=a_n A +b_nI$, and further that $A^{n+1}=a_n A^2 +b_n A=(a_n+b_n)A-(1/2)a_nI.$  Looking at the first few $(a_n,b_n)$ pairs, we have 
$$(1,0), (1,-1/2), (1/2,-1/2),(0,-1/4)$$

So $A^{4}=(-1/4)I$.  This makes it easy to compute larger powers of $A$ and see they are tending towards $0$.

Comment: This is also excellent, thank you! I always calculate matrix limits with the eigenvalues approach, and would never have thought to approach it this way. Thank you.

Comment: @poppy3345 I'm glad you like this approach.  The fact that powers of $A$ can be expressed in terms of powers less than $2$ (and if $A$ had been $n\times n$, by powers less than $n$) is sometimes useful.  However, it was a bit of luck that things simplified at the end quite as much as they did.  I was anticipating needing to find a clever argument to argue that the terms were tending towards zero.  In retrospect, looking at your eigenvalue computation, I should have realized, as $1+i$ is a real multiple of a root of unity.

Answer (score 2):

Let's do a few computations. We have:

$$A^2=A-{1\over 2}I$$

This means $A^3={A\over 2}-{I\over 2}$ and:

$$A^4=A^2-A+{1\over 4}I=-{1\over 4}I$$

We can prove by induction that

$$\begin{align}
A^{4k}&=\left({-1\over 4k}\right)^k\cdot I\\
A^{4k+1}&=\left({-1\over 4k}\right)^k\cdot A\\
A^{4k+2}&=\left({-1\over 4k}\right)^k\cdot\left(A-{1\over 2}I\right)\\
A^{4k+3}&=\left({-1\over 4k}\right)^k\cdot\left({A\over 2}-{1\over 2}I\right)
\end{align}$$

Let

$$M=\sup\{1,\|A\|,\|A-{I\over 2}\|,\|{A\over 2}-{I\over 2}\|\}$$

We have

$$\|A^n\|\leq {M\over n^{\lfloor {n\over 4}\rfloor}}\to 0$$

Answer (score 1):

You can get $A^n=A^{n-1}-1/2A^{n-2}=(A^{n-2}-1/2A^{n-3})-1/2A^{n-2}=1/2A^{n-2}-1/2A^{n-3}=-1/4A^{n-4}$. Then the conclusion is obvious by induction on k, while let n=4k+i.

Answer (score -2):

For generalisation, assume $$
        A=\begin{bmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & d \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$ Now, for every $2X2$ matrix, this equation is always valid $A^2-trace(A)A+det(A)I=0$ (prove this by youself, this is very easy). Now you can compare this equation with your original equation, you will get $a+d=-1$ and $ad-bc=\frac {1}{2}$. Assume any values of $a,b,c,d$ satistfying these equations which I had done earlier.

Assume the values $a=d=-0.5, -b=c=0.5$, then matrix will look like $$2A=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 & -1  \\
         1 & -1  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$ This matrix satisfy all the given condition.Now you can proceed. You can get very easily that $A^n=0$ as $n \to \infty$ . And also you can also use the eigen value logic to prove that $A^n=0$ as $n \to \infty$

Eigen Value Logic can also be applied. Let the eigen value of this matrix be $e_1$ and $e_2$. From given equation it is clear that $det(A)=0.5=e_1e_2$ and both eigen values are non real. So $e_1e_2=e^2=0.5$ where $|e_1|=|e_2|=e$

Now $\alpha=|A^n|=|A|^n=2^{-n}$ and as $n \to \infty$, $\alpha=0$ which clearly proves that $A^n$ has to be zero matrix because determinant of that matrix is zero, otherwise determinat of that matrix will never be zero.

Comment: Can you justify why you can make that assumption? Just because it is true for one matrix satisfying the condition does not a priori mean it is true for all matrices satisfying the condition.

Comment: I can see how in this case, $A^n = 0$ as $n \to \infty$, but I don't see how to generalize it using ``eigenvalue logic,'' can you elaborate your reasoning there, please?

Comment: @Aaron and poppy3345 Now you can see both the logics.

Comment: @VineetMangal Your edit explains how you would go from a matrix to a polynomial identity (by essentially citing the Cayley-Hamilton theorem in the $2\times 2$ case), but it is a one way process, for example any matrix conjugate to the one you listed will also satisfy the same equation. What you are missing is a statement along the lines that EVERY $2\times 2$ matrix satisfying that equation is conjugate to your matrix.  Without the matrices having some close relation to each other, you don't know that powers of your matrix will have any relation to powers of the other matrices.